# Does there exist a kernel hook to know which tty is currently active?

Tags: kernel, drivers, tty

I want to make a driver for an information panel.  One of the planned features is to indicate which terminal is active (the machine is Linux 4.9.x with no GUI or display manager of any kind).

Does there exist a kernel hook or event that triggers upon switching the active tty with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> (where <kbd>F#</kbd> is any function key in the range of <kbd>F1</kbd> to <kbd>F5</kbd>) that I could use to send a signal to my driver? Or, alternatively, how could I set up a server to listen for any <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F#</kbd> key combination entered?

Answer (score 0):

The currently active tty is given by:

```
cat /sys/class/tty/tty0/active
```

You could probably use the `inotify(7)` API to watch for changes in this file.

Comment: thanks.  I am looking for something lower level, that I could safely and reliably call in a loaded kernel module.

Comment: I don't write kernel modules, but `sysfs` is a filesystem view of kernel structures.  `/sys/class/tty/tty0/` appears to be a symlink to `/sys/devices/virtual/tty/tty0/`.  If you can access the `device` structure for `tty0`, you'll have access to its `active` member